# Calculate dates relative to input date

Tags: php

With the code I have now, it managed to return dates way off in 1969 and 1970.Example of $endDate is 23-8-2013. Day, month, year.

```
$endDte = date_create_from_format('j-n-Y', $endDate);

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 Sunday', strtotime($endDte))). date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 Saturday', strtotime($endDte)));
```

This code doesn't seem to give me a previous Sunday and the next Saturday relative to the date given so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think you'll have to explain what you expect `-1 Sunday` to actually do.

Comment: (`-1 day` is valid syntax, maybe you meant that?)

Comment: Edited, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php. It should support -1 Sunday and +1 Saturday.

Comment: @Dubastot where did you get that idea from? and again *what do you expect that to mean?*

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it's worked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_create_from_format` returns a `DateTime` object, not a string you should run through `strtotime`...:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('j-n-Y', $endDate);

$startdate = clone $date;
$startdate->modify('-1 Sunday');

$enddate = clone $date;
$enddate->modify('+1 Saturday');

echo $startdate->format('Y-m-d').' => '.$enddate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Now if I want to repeat this to get two dates, what do I do?

Comment: By cloning the object (so as to not _"destroy"_ your original data), edited it in for you.

Comment: Well, we are solving different problems (my point was mainly the difference between a `DateTime` & a string)... On the one hand, if you ever decide you want to change `Sunday-Saturday` to `Monday-Sunday`... the `lastSunday()` function would be a bit silly. On the other hand he solves the problem for _when_ it's sunday...

Comment: Can't you just do a simple check to get the day of week?

Comment: Well, you can use something like `if($date->format('w')!=0) $startDate->modify('-1 Sunday'); if($date->format('w')!=6) $enddate->modify(΅+1 Saturday');`. Be aware you need to change _both_ string / comparisons if you change the start/endday, and you need another comparison if you change from 1 week to more.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to be modifying it to be more than 1 week. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just went back into my code and reviewed what had worked previously, tested it again and it returned correct results.       $dtes = array(strtotime('-2 Thursday', $endDte), strtotime('-1 Wednesday', $endDte), strtotime('-1 Thursday', $endDte), $endDte);

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `last sunday` and `next saturday`, instead of `-1 sunday` and `+1 saturday`
Then I'd wrap them into functions, an example for the last sunday:

```
function lastSunday($ts=time(), $weeksApart=1){
  if(date('N', $ts) == 7){
    $time = $ts;
  } else{
    $time = strtotime('last sunday', $ts);
  }
  return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$weeksApart.' weeks', $ts));
}
```

Comment: The issue is, I was just testing with -1 Sunday and +1 Sunday, but in the future I will need things like -3 Sunday.

Comment: see edit. Like this you can adjust the weeks with the second param

Comment: Which method would you recommend, yours or Wrikken's?

Comment: Probably his, the `DateTime` method seems to be cleaner and more readable, though I don't have experience with it